# Sleeping AVR64DD32 and waking up from button press

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, sleep

I'm trying to put the mentioned microcontroller (AVR64DD32) to sleep and to awake it by a button(PD4) interrupt.
My code was inspired by [this tutorial](https://github.com/microchip-pic-avr-examples/avr64dd32-getting-started-with-gpio-mplabx-mcc) , but instead of blinking an LED I'm trying to wake up the uC.

The buttons are setup falling Edge.
The code looks like this:

```
volatile uint8_t buttonInterrupt = 0;

void ButtonWakeUpInt(void){
    buttonInterrupt = 1;
}
int main(void)
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    PD4_SetInterruptHandler(ButtonWakeUpInt);
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sei();
    while (1){
    if(SleepButton)
    {
        while (1)
        {
             printf("entering sleep\r\n")
             sleep_mode(); 
             ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_FORCEON)
             {
                  delay(10);
             }
             if(buttonInterrupt)
             {
                  sleep_disable(); 
                  buttonInterrupt = 0;
                  printf("I'm awake\r\n");
                  break;
             }
          }
   }
}
```

I expected the interrupt to set buttonInterrupt to 1 and execute the "if statement" waking up the microcontroller. After a button press "entering sleep" is printed once, but when i try to wake up "I'm awake" is never printed.

Comment: Where is SleepButton defined and how is that set?  What level of Sleep does SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN set?  I.E does it allow a wakeup from the button?

Comment: Hi Mike I excluded SleepButton definition here, because it's just there to enter the "sleep loop". I simplified it here, because it's in reality it's in a case statement that's triggered by Queue outputs.
[Here](https://postimg.cc/PCDBQrCx/9a50ef93) is an image of the Sleep Mode Wake-up Sources.